# JPA join user roles with project id

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have to expand user roles management. Currently I have user that can have many roles, the same for all projects. I need to define users roles per project. So, user should have many roles for many project. For every project the configuration could be different. I've read a lot of similar cases in the Internet, but none was exacly what I want.

Current entities snippets:

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

```
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private short id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
```

These entities generates joining table:

```
users_roles([PK]user_id, [PK]role_id)
```

Is there any way to expand this configuration to achieve methods like this:

```
user.setRoles(setOfRoles, projectId);
user.getRoles(projectId);
```

In that situation, the joining table shuld be:

```
users_project_roles([PK]user_id, [PK]role_id, [PK]project_id)
```

If the expected way is not possible by JPA. How should I rebuild the entities to achieve the goal?
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either map the `users_project_roles` as entity or create/reuse the users_project table and map it like this:

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserProjectAssignment> projects;
}
@Table(name = "users_project")
public class UserProjectAssignment implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserProjectAssignmentId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Project project;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_project_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    private Set<Role> roles;
}

@Embeddable
public class UserProjectAssignmentId {
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    long userId;
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    long projectId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christian. Your solution looks promising. I'm trying to implement it but currently I have this message when start server: 
```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.domain.entity.User.project[com.domain.entity.UserProjectAssignment]
```

Comment: Ok, fixed. Missing @Entity in UserProjectAssignment class and UserProjectAssignmentId class must initialize Serializable.